# Mongodb cluster backup

Tags: mongodb, database-backups

I followed the mongodb documents for my cluster backup.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-database-dumps/

When I tried to take backup of my relpicaset. The secondary node in the replicaset is not getting shutdown. I am getting following error.

```
   root@local:/$ mongo --port 22222 -u admin -p admin --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'printjson(db.adminCommand("shutdown"))'
    {
            "ok" : 0,
            "errmsg" : "unauthorized: this command must run from localhost when running db without auth"
    }
```

The admin user role is "userAdminAnyDatabase". I can not take backup if it is up. Please advise

Comment: From the error message, you aren't running that mongod with authorization enabled (e.g. with --auth on the command line), so it's not possible to shut it down remotely. You'll need to restart it with auth enabled and create the proper users for remote shutdown.

Comment: Yes wdberkeley I am not running with --auth. Actually I am deploying the mongodb cluster. So I need to start all mongodb instances with --auth enabled. After starting I need to do some operations on dbs like intiating the rs etc. For that do I need to create user first or not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with the **Cluster backup** its recommended to use `clusterAdmin` role to backup the data.Also provide the `read`access for the required database.

```
db.grantRolesToUser("backupUser", [{role: "clusterAdmin", db:"admin"}])
```